# StrongLifts 5x5 and running on alternate days

Tags: running, strength-training, programs

I want to start working on building muscles and keep athletic body.

These days I run for 2.8 mi (~ 25 mins) 5 days/week.

I am planning to start Stronglifts 5x5 program and as 5x5 is only 3 times a week, is it okay to continue running (for 2.8 mi) on days I am not doing strength training?

Stronglifts program page mentions not to do any other program with 5x5. However I enjoy the short run as my day ends.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add cardio on off days if you wish, and if you do it right. The most important thing to consider is whether or not your body is getting proper recovery.

The reason Mehdi says not to change the routine at all is because when people do, it's almost always too much. The routine is already difficult, and a BIG aspect of the 5x5 SL routine is in its rest days, your body's recovery, because you're lifting so heavy.

If you're doing HIIT on your off days, your body will not be able to recover fully for your next lifting day. If you want to add a little bit of cardio, just make certain you aren't overexerting yourself. Keep the cardio light, and you should be fine.

Comment: Solid answer. A bit of cardio won't hurt much as long as you don't overdo it.